# Function to allow for only alphabets, hyphens and apostrophes

Tags: c

As stated above, I would like to make a function that checks if all the characters in a string contains any prohibited input. The condition is that I only want to accept alphabets, hyphens and apostrophes. Below is my code which does not work the way I intended it to. If it is not an alphabet AND not an apostrophe or a hyphen, I want to change result to 0. However, when I enter a valid input like 'a-a; which is either an alphabet or hyphen, the if function still gets executed which prints "IT IS NOT ACCEPTED".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int validateInput(char word[]);

int main(void) {
    char word[33] = "a-a";
    printf("%d",validateInput(word));
}

int validateInput(char word[]) {
    int result = 1;
    int i;
    int length = strlen(word);
    for (i = 0; i <length; i++) {
        if ((isalpha(word[i]) == 0) && ((word[i] != '-') || (word[i] != '\''))) {
            printf("IT IS NOT ACCEPTED\n");
            result = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("ACCEPTED\n");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is your question, please?

Comment: `isalpha(word[i] == 0 )`?!?  What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Oops, I meant to do isalpha(word[i] ) == 0. If it is not an alphabet and it is not a hyphen or apostrophe, then i will change result to 0. If not the result will stay as 1 which tells me that word[i] is either an alphabet or a hyphen or a apostrophe.

Comment: I suggest the simpler `if (isalpha(word[i]) == 0 && word[i] != '-' && word[i] != '\'')`

Comment: Thanks sir! Now that I think about it, your method makes more sense and it helped to get my code working. However, do you know what is wrong with the conditional statement?

Comment: Yes, `(word[i] != '-') || (word[i] != '\'')` is always `true` because it can't be *both*. If one is `false`, the other is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if( !( (isalpha((unsigned char)word[i])) || (word[i] == '-') || (word[i] == '\'')) )
```

Comment: The function [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) takes an `int` parameter, not a `char` parameter. According to [§7.4 ¶2 of the ISO C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4), the expression `isalpha(word[i])` will cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if the parameter is not representable as an `unsigned char` and is not equal to the value `EOF`. Therefore, it should be written as `isalpha( (unsigned char)word[i] )`.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you issue the diagnostic at each iteration instead of at the end of the loop
- the test `(word[i] != '-') || (word[i] != '\'')` is always true.
- `isalpha()` should not be passed a `char` value that could be negative. You should cast the argument as `(unsigned char)` to avoid potential undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>

int validateInput(const char *word) {
    int result = 1;
    for (size_t i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (!isalpha((unsigned char)word[i]) && word[i] != '-' && word[i] != '\'') {
            result = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result) {
        printf("ACCEPTED\n");
    } else {
        printf("IT IS NOT ACCEPTED\n");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note however that the above function will accept an empty string, which might not be the intended behavior.

Here is a simpler version using `sscanf()` that works for ASCII:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int validateInput(const char *word) {
    int pos = 0;
    sscanf(word, "%*[-a-zA-Z']%n", &pos);
    if (pos > 0 && word[pos] == '\0') {
        printf("ACCEPTED\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("IT IS NOT ACCEPTED\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And this is a more verbose version using `strspn()` that works for all encodings:

```
#include <string.h>

int validateInput(const char *word) {
    size_t len = strspn(word, "'-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    if (len > 0 && word[len] == '\0') {
        printf("ACCEPTED\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("IT IS NOT ACCEPTED\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```